# what are the best qualifieres to uses in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, responsive

Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a consistent development environment across devices and handles most of the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on which it is displayed. At the same time, the system provides APIs that allow you to control your application's UI for specific screen sizes and densities, in order to optimize your UI design for different screen configurations. For example, you might want a UI for tablets that's different from the UI for handsets.

This leads us to this question  what are the best qualifiers to use from the list bellow:

```
A set of six generalized densities:
 ldpi (low) ~120dpi
 mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
 hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Or

```
sw600dp
sw720dp
w720dp
w1024dp
h720dp
h1024dp
```

or

A set of screen size :

```
 small  
 normal 
 large  
 xlarge
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use

```
sw600dp
sw720dp
w720dp
w1024dp
h720dp
h1024dp
```

because with those you can control *exactly* how it looks, while making it easier for you quickly tell the values.

In addition, this is the more "modern" way of defining sizes.

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html):

> One of the difficulties developers had in pre-3.2 Android devices was
>   the "large" screen size bin, which encompasses the Dell Streak, the
>   original Galaxy Tab, and 7" tablets in general. However, many
>   applications may want to show different layouts for different devices
>   in this category (such as for 5" and 7" devices), even though they are
>   all considered to be "large" screens. That's why Android introduced
>   the "Smallest-width" qualifier (amongst others) in Android 3.2.
>
> The Smallest-width qualifier allows you to target screens that have a
>   certain minimum width given in dp. For example, the typical 7" tablet
>   has a minimum width of 600 dp, so if you want your UI to have two
>   panes on those screens (but a single list on smaller screens), you can
>   use the same two layouts from the previous section for single and
>   two-pane layouts, but instead of the large size qualifier, use sw600dp
>   to indicate the two-pane layout is for screens on which the
>   smallest-width is 600 dp.